# How to make tab bar in jQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I take a tab bar from one of my project and put it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tazs4vx/), but there is too much CSS it is impossible to understand so I take useful code from the CSS and made my own [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/h7Lasuoh/) but it is 100% similar to example. But I need to make same tab bar in my jQuery mobile example.

I used `data-role ="navbar"`

Here is my final demo In which I need to add this upper tab bar instead of button

```
<div data-role="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="tabBtn" data-tabid="0">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tabBtn" data-tabid="1">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="tabBtn" data-tabid="2">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How to make tab bar same as in above fiddles?

http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/o9foej5L/1/

Comment: If you want add the line bottom, it's just on `border-bottom:` on `li`

Comment: but my li are not look same in fiddle .they are looking as button

Comment: i think you didn't get it please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4tazs4vx/..tab bar not button they are label and background colour is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo first, then explanation:

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/o9foej5L/6/)**

I added a class to the navbar:

```
<div data-role="navbar" class="myNavBar">
```

Then the following CSS does the trick:

```
.myNavBar  {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fb7923;
}
.myNavBar a {
    border-width: 0px !important;  
}
.myNavBar a.ui-btn-active {
    background-color: rgb(246, 246, 246) !important;   
    border-color: rgb(221, 221, 221) !important;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fb7923 !important;
    color: #fb7923 !important;
    padding-bottom: 6.75px;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none  !important;
}
.myNavBar a:hover {
    border-color: rgb(221, 221, 221) !important;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fb7923 !important;
    padding-bottom: 6.75px;
}
```

The first one sets the bottom border of the whole navbar to orange. The second one gets rid of all the button borders. The ui-btn-active override sets the text orange, created a thicker bottom border and adjusts the padding to keep the button the same height as the others. I also tweaked the hover state.

You should tweak these settings to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this css

```
.ui-btn-active{
 border-bottom: 3px solid #c30 !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o9foej5L/3/

You need to take help of JavaScript

```
   $(".tabBtn").on("click", function(){
         $(".tabBtn").removeClass("activeWI");
        $(this).addClass("activeWI");
    });
```

Changes to your HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="topbarWI">
        <div class="midbox">
            <div class="main-menu">
                <a runat="server" href="#" id="logoutRg" class="tabBtn fl activeWI">Tab1</a>
                <a runat="server" href="#" id="faqbtnRg" class="tabBtn fright">Tab3</a>
                <a runat="server" href="#" id="newregistrationRg" class="tabBtn mid-link">Tab2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

JS Fildle: http://jsfiddle.net/h7Lasuoh/1/

Comment: No but tab bar is not look like same as in above fiddle ..:( you underline the tab but is not buttons ..please check first two fiddles

Comment: please remove your answer

Comment: i think you didn't get it please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4tazs4vx/..tab bar not button they are label and background colour is different

Comment: @user2535959 Check my updated answer. FOr removing unwanted CSS. you will have to find each set of CSS properties and clean it up at your convinience.

Comment: thanks for answer..but that tab bar can we use in my main example?in this http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/o9foej5L/1. of button or ul li

Comment: I need to add tat tab bar in main example ..your answer is correct but how we add this in main example

Comment: it is same http://jsfiddle.net/4tazs4vx/1/ you have to apply these changes, add jquery reference and add js code and change html classes

Comment: @user2535959 where is ur main example, first two fiddles looks same

Comment: here is third fiddle main fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/o9foej5L/1/.here i take ul and li having one two and third in that example I need to add tab baar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60260/discussion-between-user2535959-and-habo).